# How can I pull out the Max value of a field with the name on that record?

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb, executescalar

How can pull selected fields of a record from an access database and put it into a label? This is what I have so far:

```
Using conn As New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)

conn.Open()

Using cmd As OleDbCommand = conn.CreateCommand
    If cb_Stat.Text = "Top Scorer" Then
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(Goals) FROM PlayerDatabase"
        Label1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    End If

End Using

conn.Close()
```

End Using

What happens is the max number of goals scored by a player from the playerdatabase is put into the string which is 10. How can I get it to also pull out the data from the Forename and Surname fields of the same record and display it as "John Doe 10" instead of just "10"

Answer (score 3):

You can use `order by` and get only one row.  The ANSI standard method is:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM PlayerDatabase p
ORDER BY goals DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Not all databases support the last clause.  Some use `select top 1`.  Others `limit 1`, and some are even more arcane.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Max` aggregate use `order by` plus `top 1` to get the player who scored max number of `goals`.

Then concatenate the `Forename, Surname, Goals` columns. Try this.

```
SELECT Top 1 Forename &" "& Surname &" "& cast(Goals as varchar(10)) 
FROM PlayerDatabase
order by Goals desc
```

Comment: I changed my originial SQL statement for what you suggested and now I'm getting an error at the  Label1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar line. The error is: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll